# Is there a way to return multiple html files in Google App Scripts using one doGet() function?

Tags: html, web-applications, charts, google-apps-script

I have html files that have pie charts for the months January through march. i.e. a January Html file, February html file, etc. Is there a way to return all those html files using one doGet() function or is this not possible?

Comment: You could use query strings to identify the individual pages. `?page=pagename`  and use e.querystring to access everything after the question mark. Check out URL parameters on this [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

Comment: @Cooper Could you provide an example of query strings being used? The documentation isn't as intuitive as I hoped.

Comment: I could, but I'd prefer seeing what you come up with on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep the files separate but you would have to concatenate them all into one before they could be served by the doGet():

```
<< Code.gs >>

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate()
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent()
}

<< Index.html >>
.
.
.
<?!= include('file1.html') ?>
<?!= include('file2.html') ?>
<?!= include('file3.html') ?>
.
.
.
```

Comment: Tried running doGet() but getting an error saying that function getTemplateFromFile can't be found in object Html service.

Comment: I'd remembered that name wrong should have been createTemplateFromFile(). Try it now.

Comment: This code almost worked, I could combine the two html outputs but some of the data from the February sheet isn't appearing. The data that isn't showing up is the data table, line chart and material line chart. The pie charts and bar graph were created though.

Comment: Found my error. The function names for the data table, line chart and material line chart were the same. Giving them unique names solved the problem.